# How to use widgets AMI.js

Tags: ami.js

In the example code for the widgets in AMI.js they get the WidgetsHandle from 'base/widgets/widgets.handle'. Is there a way to access the widgets when just using the AMI library without access to the whole repo? I've tried doing

```
var wh = new AMI.WidgetsHandle(a,b,c,d)
```

But it says it's not a constructor.

(The example is https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami/blob/dev/examples/widget_handle/widget_handle.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "AMI.HandleWidget" instead.

It is been exported [there](https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami/blob/dev/src/widgets/widgets.js#L8-L15).

You code should look like:

```
const handle = new AMI.HandleWidget(...)
```

HTH,